# Why does "for (i = 100; i <= 0; --i)" loop forever?

Tags: c++, c, loops, comparison, unsigned

```
unsigned int i;
for (i = 100; i <= 0; --i)
    printf("%d\n",i);
```

Comment: Prepare to be overhelmed by answers

Comment: Depends on what you want the code to do...

Comment: @aaa: All of them different. :)

Answer (score 11):

Should be `i >= 0` in the second condition in the loop if you want it to loop from 100 to 0.

That, and as others have pointed out, you'll need to change your definition of `i` to a signed integer (just `int`) because when the counter is meant to be -1, it will be some other positive number because you declared it an `unsigned int`.

Comment: "Should be i >= 0 if you want it to loop from 100 to 0." -- nope, i >= 0 would yield an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't think so?  Thought the loop kicked out when the second statement in the loop was false?

Comment: "Thought the loop kicked out when the second statement in the loop was false?" -- yes.  "Should be i >= 0 in the second condition in the loop if you want it to loop from 100 to 0." -- still no, that would yield an infinite loop.

Comment: @John: It won't ever be false.  When it is equal to zero, it will get decremented and overflow back to maximum `uint` size.  To infinity...

Comment: I was really concerned I had been doing for loops wrong all these years! ;)

Comment: I'll vote for ya now that you've fixed the unsigned int underflow problem as well.

Answer (score 10):

Since `i` is unsigned, it will *never* be less than zero.  Drop `unsigned`. Also, swap the `<=` for `>=`.

Answer (score 7):

Since `i` is unsigned, the expression `i <= 0` is suspicious and equivalent to `i == 0`.

And the code won't print anything, since the condition `i <= 0` is false on its very first evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

If the code is supposed to do nothing, nothing is wrong with it.

Assuming that you want it to print the loop index `i` from 100 to 1, you need to change `i <= 0` to `i > 0`.

Because it is an unsigned int, you cant use `i >= 0` because that will cause it to infinitely loop.

Comment: I don't completely agree. If the code is supposed to do nothing, there's way too much code there. :)

Answer (score 2):

The <= 0 maybe? since it is `false` from the start

For loop

- init: i = 100
- test: i <= 0    // false on first pass

Change the test to `i > 0`  (100 times)

or `i >= 0` (101 times) together with the declaration `signed int i;` so that it actually decreases down to -1.  An unsigned int will go from 0 up to max-int (overflow).

Answer (score 2):

The loop checks for `i <= 0;`

`i` is never less-than-or-equal to zero. Its initial value is 100.

Answer (score 2):

Technically nothing is wrong with that code.  The test for i <= 0 is strange since i is unsigned, but it's technically valid, true when i is 0 and false otherwise.  In your case i never happens to be 0.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you meant the test to be `i > 0`.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately it looks like you did his homework for him.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to print all numbers from 100 down to 0 then you need

```
unsigned int i;
for (i = 100; i >= 0; --i)
    printf("%d\n",i);
```

The first time your loop ran in your original code, i was 100. The test '100 <= 0' failed and therefore nothing was showing.

Comment: There's also the issue that the loop won't kick out because `i` is declared unsigned.  See the discussion in my answer.