# warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true

Tags: c, gcc

I have the following error when compiling a C file:

```
t_memmove.c: In function ‘ft_memmove’:
ft_memmove.c:19: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true
```

Here's the full code, via `cat ft_memmove.c`:

```
#include "libft.h"
#include <string.h>

void    *ft_memmove(void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n)
{
    char    *s1c;
    char    *s2c;
    size_t  i;

    if (!s1 || !s2 || !n)
    {
        return s1;
    }
    i = 0;
    s1c = (char *) s1;
    s2c = (char *) s2;
    if (s1c > s2c)
    {
        while (n - i >= 0) // this triggers the error
        {
            s1c[n - i] = s2c[n - i];
            ++i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (i < n)
        {
            s1c[i] = s2c[i];
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return s1;
}
```

I do understand that size_t is unsigned and that both integers will be >= 0 because of that. But since I'm subtracting one from the other, I don't get it. Why does this error come up?

Comment: The result on an arithmetic operation of two unsigned integers is also an unsigned integer and thus by definition greater or equal to zero. If in your example `i` is greater than `n` the result of the subtraction will "wrap" to a (large) positive number. You should probably check `n >= i` instead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you subtract two unsigned integers in C, the result will be interpreted as unsigned. It doesn't automatically treat it as signed just because you subtracted. One way to fix that is use `n >= i` instead of `n - i >= 0`.

Comment: If this is the case, how come does this program print "minus"? 
```
    uint8_t a = 2;
    uint8_t b = 4;
    
    if (a - b < 0) cout << "minus";
```

Comment: @mnj according to the standard, since an `int` can hold any `uint8_t` value (a.k.a., an `unsigned char`) then the `uint8_t` is promoted to `int` in this context, and so `a - b < 0` is true.

Answer (score 4):

consider this loop:

```
for(unsigned int i=5;i>=0;i--)
{

}
```

This loop will be infinite because whenever i becomes -1 it'll be interprated as a very large possitive value as sign bit is absent in `unsigned int`.

This is the reason a warning is generated here

Comment: I met the problem. Any references to interpreted this problem? But the output in `printf` still a negative number, like -1 etc.

Comment: I've solved my problem as: `unsigned int i,j;` `for (j=6,i=j-1;j>0;j--,i=j-1){}` 
. My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066362/why-is-comparing-if-an-unsigned-int-0-a-pointless-comparison/44098861#44098861).

Answer (score 2):

According to section `6.3.1.8` of the draft C99 standard *Usual arithmetic conversions*, since they are both of the same type, the result will also be `size_t`. The section states:

> [...]Unless explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of the result[...]

and later on says:

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.

mathematically you can just move the `i` over to the other side of the expression like so:

```
 n >= i
```

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic on `unsigned` results in an `unsigned` and that's why you are getting this warning. Better to change `n - i >= 0` to `n >= i`.

Answer (score 0):

Operations with unsigned operands are performed in the domain of unsigned type. Unsigned arithmetic follows the rules of modular arithmetic. This means that the result will *never* be negative, even if you are subtracting something from something. For example `1u - 5u` does not produce `-4`. If produces `UINT_MAX - 3`, which is a huge positive value congruent to `-4` modulo `UINT_MAX + 1`.