# WHY is comparison of unsigned expression < 0 always false

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

So, if you ever try evaluating an unsigned integer < 0, you get a warning that says:

> comparison of unsigned expression < 0 always false

This is because unsigned integers are never technically negative, here's the best explanation I've found so far: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20074178/2611971)

But if I run something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    testInt--;
    NSLog(@"TestInt = %li", testInt);
    
    // WARNING AREA //
    if (testInt < 0) {
        NSLog(@"HI");
    }
 
    // OK //
    if (testInt == -1) {
        NSLog(@"Negative ...");
    }
}
```

I'll get output:

> TestInt = 4
>
> TestInt = 3
>
> TestInt = 2
>
> TestInt = 1
>
> TestInt = 0
>
> TestInt = -1
>
> Negative ...
>
> TestInt = -2
>
> TestInt = -3
>
> TestInt = -4
>
> TestInt = -5

You can see that the number evaluates fine for negative values, and can equal -1.

#### Update

After @RobP's answer, I noticed a problem with my logging, it should be `%lu` which gives the output:

> TestInt = 4
>
> TestInt = 3
>
> TestInt = 2
>
> TestInt = 1
>
> TestInt = 0
>
> TestInt = 18446744073709551615
>
> Negative ...
>
> TestInt = 18446744073709551614
>
> TestInt = 18446744073709551613
>
> TestInt = 18446744073709551612
>
> TestInt = 18446744073709551611

However, my question still stands because it can still evaulate `numb == -1` and not `numb < 0`:

#### Question

Why can a NSUInteger be simultaneously equal to -1 but not less than 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your display of the numbers, not the numbers. This line:

```
NSLog(@"TestInt = %li", testInt);
```

takes your unsigned integer and displays it as if it's a signed int. Change the format specifier to %lu and you should see what your values "really" are to the machine.

EDIT:
Thanks to Massa for comment below about the equality of the comparison. When you compare your unsigned variable to the signed value -1, the -1 gets changed into an unsigned value (normally max value of an unsigned int) and they are equal, just as when you take an unsigned int equal to 0 and subtract 1, it becomes UINT_MAX.

Comment: in other words, testInt is never really equal to -1. It just has the same binary representation that a signed int of -1 happens to have, but these bits (may) have a different meaning when interpreted as unsigned.

Comment: I would like to add to that: what @Logan is **really** doing is comparing `TestInt` with `((unsigned)-1)` (normally that would be `UINT_MAX`...) because the `operator==` will "promote" something to `unsigned` if the other side (testInt, _in casu_) is `unsigned`.

Comment: @RobP - I updated for your answer, but I'm still unsure why it will pass `numb == -1` but not `numb < 0`

Comment: @Massa's comment above explains it well. the compiler changes the -1 to an unsigned in order to be able to compare it with TestInt. So both TestInt and -1 (after promotion) are equal to UINT_MAX.

Comment: And comparison: numb < 0, both are unsigned so min(numb)==0 => 0 < 0 => always false.

Comment: I get it, so when it compares it to 0, an unsigned it can be 0, and when it converts it to an unsigned, it will still be 0. Any number that would initially be less than 0 is converted to an unsigned large number and will always be greater than 0. Thanks everybody for answer and constructive comments!

Answer (score 1):

There's no "technically" about it. Unsigned integers are **never** negative, full stop. They either hold `0` or a positive value. This doesn't need any further explanation.

They don't "remember" if they were originally assigned from a signed value, or anything like that.

As you discovered, your original code caused undefined behaviour by using the wrong format specifier for `printf`. All that tells you is (at best) that the bits used to store this unsigned int are the same bits that would be used to store a particular signed int.  But the meaning of the bits is different, that's what data types do: they tell how a certain set of bits should be interpreted as a value.

In the code `numb == -1` , there is a problem. You are using `==` on two different data types. In Java for example, the compiler rejects this outright. However, in C and C++ there are some rules called *implicit conversions* that will guess what you were most likely trying to do, and perform a conversion on one of the operands to match the other one.

In this particular case, the rule is that if one operand has type `signed T` and the other `unsigned T`, then the signed one is convered to unsigned.  So your code actually behaves like:

```
numb == (unsigned long)-1
```

(assuming `numb` is `unsigned long`). Further, part of the definition of `unsigned long` is that when you assign to it an out-of-range value, that value is adjusted modulo `ULONG_MAX + 1` until it comes in range. So the code is also equivalent to:

```
numb == ULONG_MAX
```

This is why the first output you see after `0` is `ULONG_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically your number is never equal to `-1`. When you compare your unsigned number to a **signed** `-1`, the last is converted to an unsigned as well, hence yielding a value that is equal to `testInt`.

The comparison of an `unsigned` versus a `0` and mainly using the less operator is still always false, because `0` is an unsigned, hence no promotion from one data type to another doesn't takes place.