# How to solve the warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true inside a loop

Tags: c

I have the following loop:

```
for(register size_t j=i-1;j>=0;--j){

}
```

I want the loop to go until 0, but counting 0 as a new loop.

The compiler issues the following warning:

> warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074073/warning-comparison-of-unsigned-expression-0-is-always-true) question, I understand the problem.

I solved mine, by switching the variable to an `int`.

```
for(register int j=i-1;j>=0;--j){

}
```

Is there any more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: Check that its not equal rather than greater than 0, and don't decrement i before the loop: `for(register size_t j = i;j != 0;--j)`

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `i == 0`?

Comment: It's intereasting that you are using `register`, why is that?

Comment: @dxiv one more iteration

Comment: @anastaciu just to hold my variable, so that the computations will be faster

Comment: @DuarteArribas: Did you check your compiler agrees with you? Or disagrees if you omit it? Don't do premature optimisations. `register` will be ignored by all modern compilers for optimisation reasons.

Comment: @DuarteArribas Neither of the posted `for` loops will do "*one more iteration*". The first one will still be an infinite loop, or perhaps run `SIZE_MAX-1` times if you modify the stop condition, while the second one will be skipped altogether. So the question remains what it is that you expect to happen in that case.

Comment: @DuarteArribas, I see, note that using register is not a guarantee that the variable will be saved in the register, it's a *suggestion* and its usage was deprecated in C++17, it's now a reserved keyword.

Comment: @anastaciu I am not using c++, I'm using c. I undestand the register is just a suggestion, and many compilers do their optimizations, and ignore the keyword. Is register also deprecated in c?

Comment: @DuarteArribas it was not deprecated in C, sorry about that, I thought it was a C++ question, my bad, in any case, as you stated, it doesn't do much either.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
for(register size_t j=i;j-- > 0;)
```

The loop will start for j equal to i-1 and the last iteration will run for j equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to *decrement* inside the loop:

```
for (size_t j = i; j > 0; ){
    j--;
}
```

`int` is not a proper substitute for `size_t`. POSIX has `ssize_t` (the signed counterpart) that is slightly more appropriate. The `register` keyword is most likely useless.

Comment: but should you actually use POSIX, since is not standard?

Comment: @DuarteArribas POSIX **is** a standard. It is even an [**ISO** standard](https://www.iso.org/standard/50516.html). The nice thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from.